# Android activity Button

Tags: android

I have two buttons in my first android frame. ok button and cancel button. Cancel button will terminate the application. I want another button which appears in a new frame after I click on ok. I used setOnClickListener. But that button instead of appearing on a new frame after I click ok, appears in the same frame as Ok exists ,under cancel. I even created a new Button in main.xml and a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml. should I write them in a special way? I don't know exactly that what can be the problem. please help me.

Comment: If you show us some code it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you create new Layout file for next Activity under Layout folder?

And

and set like as 
`setContentView(R.layout.second)`

in new Activity?

Comment: When I want to create setContentView(R.layout.second), it says that I need to create field second in type layout. Then it creates it is AndroidManifest.xml but it delete it automatically.

Comment: Is second what you're calling your xml layout for the activity? You need to replace 'second' with whatever you want the xml layout to be for that activity.